# A generalization of the Borsuk Ulam theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Is there a  compact  $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ or, more generaly,  a compact $n$-dimensional topological space  $M$  with the  following  property?

"For every  continuous  map $f:M \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ there  are  points  $a,b,c \in M $  with $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)$."

This  is  motivated  by the following  obvious consequence of the   Borsuk-Ulam theorem:

"For every  continuous  map  $f:S^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ there  are points $a, b \in S^n$  with $f(a)=f(b)$."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If M is allowed to be a simplicial complex, five $n$-simplices with a common $(n-1)$-dimensional face should do the job. If $M$ should be a manifold, take any closed non-orientable one.

The multiplicity of maps between manifolds can be studied with the help of characteristic classes, see [this preprint of Roman Karasev](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0660) and [this preprint of Roman Karasev and Pavle Blagojevic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06723). For example, any continuous map $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ sends some four points in $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^4$ to the same point in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Another generalization of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem (more close to it in the spirit) deals with spaces with a group action (like $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on the sphere) such that for any map to $\mathbb{R}^n$ some orbit is sent to a point. This is discussed in detail in Section 6 of

*Matoušek, Jiří*, [**Using the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. Lectures on topological methods in combinatorics and geometry. Written in cooperation with Anders Björner and Günter M. Ziegler**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-76649-0), Universitext. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-540-00362-5/pbk; 978-3-540-76649-0/ebook). xii, 214~p. (2008). [ZBL1234.05002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1234.05002).

Comment: Thank  you again  for  your  very interesting answer. It  seems that the  powerfull method of characteristic  classes  is  more  applicable in compact  cases for  example  $\mathbb{R}P^4$ rather than non compact  bases. As  an example of  non compact  case,   I am   wondering  if this  question is an  elementary question: "Is there  a  continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$  such that  every level set is  a  finite  set?

Comment: There is no such a map. Let $p$ be an interior point of $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (if there is no interior point, then $f$ is constant). The restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus f^{-1}(p)$ is a continuous map onto a disconnected set. Hence $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus f^{-1}(p)$ is disconnected, in particular $f^{-1}(p)$ is infinite (even uncountable).

Comment: @lvan  thank you. What about the same question for $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.?